# Strange error with using slash

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

I am using the PHP library for Sendgrid (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php).          Following the instructions, I had to use this line of code:

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
```

I get the error:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/d/public_html/ac/application/controllers/email.php on line 20

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/d/public_html/ac/application/controllers/email.php on line 20
```

Is there something wrong with using `'\'`? Seems strange to me... How can I get this to work?

Comment: Upgrade your php version to 5.3+

Comment: PHP 5.2 reached end-of-life in December 2010. No new security fixes are released for 5.2 since January 2011. That end-of-life was announced two years ago, so nobody should be running 5.2 anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `\` is part of [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), a new feature in PHP 5.3.